# Как сделать нестандартную форма блока?

Tags: css

Как можно сделать такую форму с помощью CSS? 
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Если речь идет только о форме, без подробностей, то можно это сделать с помощью border. Например, если у блока border-top:10px silid #fff и border-right:10px solid transparent, получится ровный треугольник. Если этот треугольник прицепить к прямоугольнику (например, в псевдо-элемент :after) справа, получится форма, как на изображении (естественно, размеры border-ов нужно будет поменять под свои нужды)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Если это элемент дизайна, то есть минимум 2 простых способа:

1. `transform: skewX(-20deg);`
2. `background-image: linear-gradient(-20deg, grey 90%, transparent 90%);`

Если в блоке планируется текст со скошенным правым выравниванием, то вам нужно использовать `shapes`. Но методика экспериментальная, мало каким браузерами поддерживается. Вот статья на эту тему http://frontender.info/css-shapes/

Answer (score 3):

**Один пример на shapes второй на svg**

```css
.a {
  width: 300px;
  height: 200px;
  background: red;
  -webkit-clip-path: polygon(0 0, 100% 0, 71% 100%, 0% 100%);
  clip-path: polygon(0 0, 100% 0, 71% 100%, 0% 100%);
  margin: auto;
}
.b {
  width: 300px;
  height: 200px;
  margin: auto;
}
```

```html
shapes
<div class="a"></div>
<br />
<br />
svg
<div class="b">
  <svg width="300px" height="200px">
    <polygon points="10 190, 10 10,290 10,200 190" style="fill:red; fill-opacity:1; stroke:;" />
  </svg>
</div>
```

Внизу (в розовом) ссылка на инструкции

> https://css-tricks.com/working-with-shapes-in-web-design/

Comment: Если внутри блока будет текст, куда его вставлять в случае с svg?